# Child Actor messes the parent character movement

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to use child actors in the following way: I have my main character with a child Actor, I want that to be the chasis for my ship, this will have some functionality so having it as a BP should work fine. The chasis will also follow the same principle and I want to attach different mods to the chasis but first I want to use the bare chasis inside my character.

However, when I select my chasisBP in the child Actor my character stops moving. This is only when the child Actor is setted. What I had before was just a static mesh and with that I can move freely.